# SQL query to pick the correct substring value from the column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table with the column Brand need to extract the correct string as in the output table.

### Source Table

| Brand |
| --- |
| (NORLANE) MADDERN 1200 (CONTEMPORARY 1 FACADE) |
| **do not use**ASCENT 2600 ASPEN |
| **do not use**EVOLUTION 2300 ONTARIO |
| **do not use**MERCHISTON 3800 TRADITIONAL |
| AERO 1600 BLAKE |
| ALBANY 1700 ASPEN (GENESIS) |
| Albion 161 - Matisse - Discontinued |
| Alexander 159 - Coastal |
| Almeda 344 - Huntington |
| Mendelsohn 234 Swift - Drysdale |
| Andre Swift 235 - Condor - In progress |
| HARLECH 333 |
| Seymour 284 - Drysdale - Master |
| OLSEN DUPLEX 2100 COMTEMPORARY (LOT 1 & 2) |

### Output required

| Brand |
| --- |
| MADDERN 1200 |
| ASCENT 2600 |
| EVOLUTION 2300 |
| MERCHISTON 3800 |
| AERO 1600 |
| ALBANY 1700 |
| Albion 161 |
| Alexander 159 |
| Almeda 344 |
| Mendelsohn 234 |
| Andre Swift 235 |
| HARLECH 333 |
| Seymour 284 |
| OLSEN DUPLEX 2100 |

```
Script 
------------
SELECT *

INTO  #tmpTest
FROM
(
SELECT '(NORLANE) MADDERN 1200 (CONTEMPORARY 1 FACADE)' Brand
UNION ALL
SELECT '**do not use**ASCENT 2600 ASPEN'
UNION ALL
SELECT '**do not use**EVOLUTION 2300 ONTARIO'
UNION ALL
SELECT '**do not use**MERCHISTON 3800 TRADITIONAL'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'AERO 1600 BLAKE'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ALBANY 1700 ASPEN (GENESIS)'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Albion 161 - Matisse - Discontinued'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Alexander 159 - Coastal'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Almeda 344 - Huntington'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Mendelsohn 234 Swift - Drysdale'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Andre Swift 235 - Condor - In progress'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'HARLECH 333'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Seymour  284  - Drysdale - Master'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'OLSEN DUPLEX 2100 COMTEMPORARY (LOT 1 & 2)'
)R
```

Used the following query, there is an issue with the query which is not returning the proper output.

> ```
> SELECT Brand,LEFT(s2.s, p2.p) as CorrectBrand
> FROM #tmpTest
> CROSS APPLY(SELECT REPLACE(Brand, '**do not use**',''))s1(s) /* Source string with text removed */
> CROSS APPLY(SELECT CHARINDEX(' ', s1.s))p1(FirstSpace) /* Find the pos of first space */
> CROSS APPLY(SELECT CHARINDEX(')', s1.s))b(ClosePar) /* Find pos of first close parenthesis */
> CROSS APPLY(SELECT IIF(ClosePar < FirstSpace and ClosePar > 0, STUFF(s1.s, 1, ClosePar + 1, ''), s1.s))s2(s) /* Remove content up to first closing parenthesisif relevant */
> CROSS APPLY(SELECT CHARINDEX(' ', s2.s, FirstSpace + 1))p2(p); /* Pos of second space */
> ```

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: *"Used the following query from Stu,"* Please follow the [referencing guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) when including content that is not your own; you state the name of the author, however, you do not link to the original source nor do you put the content in a quoteblock.

Comment: I can't see how people can help you, cause there's no rule regarding how people should split the string into the desired result, and the result is not clearly defined too.

Comment: You already asked this once, and the answer was accepted, so what do you need here that you haven't got

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0):

Approaches like this almost always lead to discovery of new exceptions, the better way to solve this is to store the correct strings. (Perhaps that's what you hope to do?)

Anyway, here is a similar approach but which meets the current expected result:

```
SELECT
    Brand
  , ca3.CorrectBrand
FROM #tmpTest
CROSS APPLY (SELECT REPLACE(Brand, '**do not use**','')
            ) ca1(s)
CROSS APPLY (select substring(ca1.s,1,   
               PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', ca1.s) + CHARINDEX(' ',(substring(ca1.s,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', ca1.s),100) + ' '))-2
               ) /* substring up to end of digits */
            ) ca2(s)  
CROSS APPLY (SELECT trim(substring(ca2.s, coalesce(CHARINDEX(')', ca2.s)+1,1),100))
            ) ca3(CorrectBrand) /* remove text within (...) */
```

| Brand | CorrectBrand |
| --- | --- |
| (NORLANE) MADDERN 1200 (CONTEMPORARY 1 FACADE) | MADDERN 1200 |
| **do not use**ASCENT 2600 ASPEN | ASCENT 2600 |
| **do not use**EVOLUTION 2300 ONTARIO | EVOLUTION 2300 |
| **do not use**MERCHISTON 3800 TRADITIONAL | MERCHISTON 3800 |
| AERO 1600 BLAKE | AERO 1600 |
| ALBANY 1700 ASPEN (GENESIS) | ALBANY 1700 |
| Albion 161 - Matisse - Discontinued | Albion 161 |
| Alexander 159 - Coastal | Alexander 159 |
| Almeda 344 - Huntington | Almeda 344 |
| Mendelsohn 234 Swift - Drysdale | Mendelsohn 234 |
| Andre Swift 235 - Condor - In progress | Andre Swift 235 |
| HARLECH 333 | HARLECH 333 |
| Seymour 284 - Drysdale - Master | Seymour 284 |
| OLSEN DUPLEX 2100 COMTEMPORARY (LOT 1 & 2) | OLSEN DUPLEX 2100 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lUvV-k8W)